# Determining equality for unknown types

Tags: c#, .net, observablecollection, iequalitycomparer, compression

I need to check the given instance is matching with the collection (Both are unknown types).

Have a look

```
void Main()
{
    // Employee "John" Object got from Service Layer #1
    Object obj1 = Client1.GetObject("John");

    // Employee "John" Object got from Service Layer #2
    Object obj2 = Client2.GetObject("John");

    bool flag = CheckEquality(obj1, obj2); // Both objects are Unknown Type
}
```

The Equality Check Method:

```
public bool CheckEquality(object obj1, object obj2)
{
    // Solution for Determining equality for unknown types
}
```

For example - consider the Following code: (Only for understanding purpose)

**Scenario #1**

```
public class EmpPerson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**`obj1`** holds the instance `new EmpPerson() { ID = 1, Name = "John", Address = "Los Angeles" };`

**`obj2`** holds the instance `new EmpPerson() { ID = 1, Name = "John", Address = "Los Angeles" };`

**Scenario #2**

**`obj1`** holds the value `"John Smith"`.

**`obj2`** holds the value `"John Smith"`.

**Scenario #3**

**`obj1`** holds the value `"John Smith"`.

**`obj2`** holds the instance `new EmpPerson() { ID = 1, Name = "John", Address = "Los Angeles" };`

**Scenario #4**

**`obj1`** holds the value `new UnknownTypeA()`.

**`obj2`** holds the value `new UnknownTypeX()`.

I need to Check both the objects are identical.

Kindly asssit me. how to check the equality for unknown types.

Comment: So what other types might be involved? As per comments earlier in another question, might the type have any "hidden" state, not exposed by fields? Can it contain a collection? Can it contain a `Random` property, as an example of a type which hides its state? Can it contain circular references? This isn't generally possible, but if you constrain the types involved, you could do it with reflection. (You do need to be careful about circular references though...)

Comment: @JonSkeet - please give you answer...

Comment: In Scenario #2, are `obj1` and `obj2` simply strings, or are they also of type `EmpPerson` but you only know the name?

Comment: I've asked for clarification - I can't answer without clarification.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I added one more Scenario too.

Comment: @JonSkeet - it contain a random property,

Comment: I suggest that, force obj1 and obj2 implement the same interface. In the interface add an method which return a string that can identify the object. Use that string to compare two objects.

Comment: Maybe your can check via reflection are they of the same type and call Equals in that case. Otherwise you can make compare as it makes in value types by default - list all public fields, and compare their names, types and values, with recousion if needed. It's not an universal solution, but it will be usefull in most cases.

Comment: @Anton - in the unknown type, how could I check the equality for the property wise.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I added one more Scenario too.

Comment: You really need to explain **_how_** you want to check for equality. If `obj1` only holds the name, while `obj2` holds the same name together with an ID and address, are they then equal?

Comment: @LarsKristensen - I given the Class `EmpPerson` only for understanding purpose. From service, I can consume any unknown data, I need to check both the unknown data are same. For example Scenario #1, I need to check all the properties.

Comment: @LarsKristensen - just consider Scenario #4, how could you know the properties ?

Comment: By "it contain a random property" do you mean the types can contain a property of type `System.Random`? If so, it's game over - you really can't compare `Random` instances for equality.

Comment: It would also help if you'd give the expected results for the scenarios - in scenario4, if `obj1` and `obj2` have the same properties, but they're of different types, should that count as them being equal or not?

Answer (score 1):

OK I think there are some points you are missing here...

First of all, **what do you mean by equality ?**

Are two objects equal when they hold the same reference ?
Are they equal when they have a common property that is the same ?
Or when ?

Second (and maybe more important), **why do you need to check for equality of objects you don't know ?**

If you don't even know the types of your objects, what's the point of saying they're equals ? You cannot even use them...

And if you know the types of your objects, then you know how to compare them.

You added scenario case #4, **why do you compare two objects of different types when you don't know any type ?**

In OOP, you cannot compare objects of different types, because it doesn't make sense, you can't compare apples and pears...

So that's why we usually create Interfaces that hold the common parts of different types, or that we make methods to transform an object type in another.

The solution I give here, implies that you have control over the objects implementation.

You may want to overload the Equals() method (inherited from Object).

```
public class EmpPerson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        EmpPerson cmp = (EmpPerson)obj;
        return ID.Equals(cmp.ID);
    }
}
```

And whenever you need to compare them :

```
obj1.Equals(obj2);
```

This however brings the restrictions that objects need to be of the same type, whatever the type.

*NB : Error checking has not been implemented here, you need to do it...*

Comment: I'm getting the object from the service. I don't know, what type of object it is. That's the problem.

Comment: @IRPunch OK I thought you did wrote the code for the objects. Then what do you want ? Is it possible to compare two things that you have no idea of what they are ?

Comment: Have a look in Scenario #4

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the [Compare-Net-Objects deep equals library](https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects) which can be used to perform a deep compare of objects via reflection.

Answer (score 1):

this code will compare without recoursion objects by type and by public fields list. It can be improved by adding recoursion, and properties. But it will not be soluton for all cases, of couse.

```
bool AreEquals(object a, object b)
{
  if (a == null && b == null) return true;
  if (a == null || b == null) return false;      

  var typeA = a.GetType();
  var typeB = b.GetType();

  if (typeA.Equals(typeB)) return a.Equals(b);

  var fieldsA = typeA.GetFields().Where(field => field.IsPublic).ToArray();
  var fieldsB = typeB.GetFields().Where(field => field.IsPublic).ToArray();

  if (fieldsA.Length != fieldsB.Length) return false;

  foreach(var field in fieldsA)
  {
     var other = fieldsB.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FieldType.Equals(field.FieldType) && f.Name.Equals(field.Name));
     if (other == null) return false;

     if (!field.GetValue(a).Equals(other.GetValue(b))) return false;  
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to serialize the objects and compare the serialized output.

[Binary serialization for deep object comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616610/c-sharp-compare-the-data-in-two-object-models)

This can be either binary or xml, or whatever. This is very generic and you can influence the serialization behavior with out-of-the-box utilities.